# How do I create an RTMP video encoder in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube, rtmp, youtube-livestreaming-api

How do I create an **RTMP video encoder in JavaScript** with Node.js to live stream at YouTube. I wanna live stream a html page using JavaScript to live stream at YouTube